# GameObject Selection and Deslection in Unity

Tags: events, unity-game-engine, click, touch, gameobject

I want the GameObject to be selected OnMouseDown() and if I again click/touch on the same GameObject it should be deselected so that I Can have separate events.
Need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommed that you dont use OnMouseDown() but the new event trigger interfaces which you can look at here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.html. As they give you more options on what is being clicked . For example you can do this

```
public bool Selected = false;
    public override void OnPointerDown( PointerEventData data )
    {
        if(Selected){ //put logic here i cant remmember the names }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will implement it.